# How to feed multiple files to a background process using Makefile

Tags: c, batch-file, makefile, c-preprocessor

I have a Makefile where a single target depends on multiple files--each of which must be processed separately (without giving intermediate output files). My specific scenario is more complicated:

I have C source from which I'd like to extract enum definitions. There are a few wrinkles which I cannot change:

1. The compiler isn't GCC--it's a customized compiler made by Cosmic Software.
2. In addition to the compiler, I can run the parser (let's call it parser.exe) by itself and it has the option (`-e`) to output preprocessed source on STDOUT.
3. make is actually a proprietary version which comes with the PTC Integrity software package. It doesn't support loops--if I want to use loops, I'd have to do Windows batch scripting.
4. This is all running on Windows

I've written a utility (using C# and ANTLR), let's call it ExtractEnums.exe, which extracts enums (and evaluates expressions) from C source so long as that source has been preprocessed. The preprocessed source in its entirety weighs in at a little over 30 MB. Rather than write the pre-processed source to disk using the Cosmic parser, I've chosen to pipe it into ExtractEnums.exe. Since I need to invoke the parser for each source file, I need to use a named pipe instead of just the pipe (`|`) operator. On Windows, named pipes don't get real filenames, that's why you'll see `ExtractEnums.exe -client` to write to the pipe and the background process `ExtractEnums.exe -server` which reads from the pipe in the example below.

```
############################################################################
# Dummy files - these will never exist
#
D_FILES = $(SRCS:.c=.dummy)                       # All dummy files

server :
    cmd /c start /B ExtractEnums.exe -server > temp.pipe

%.dummy : %.c server
    cmd /c parser.exe $(DEFINES_AND_OPTS) -e $^ | cmd /c ExtractEnums.exe -client

# Extract enums from all the preprocessed source:
%.enums : $(D_FILES)
    cmd /c echo ;;exit;; | cmd /c ExtractEnums.exe -client
    cmd /c move temp.pipe $@
```

This all runs if I call `make product_name.enums`. `SRCS` is a list of all the source files. `;;exit;;` is a special string I send to `ExtractEnums.exe -server` to tell it to exit. Here's the problem:

To loop over all the sources and feed them into the preprocessor, I made a list of `.dummy` files that will never exist. Since they never exist, the targets are always out of date. This means that calling `make product_name.enums` will always run all the sources through the preprocessor even if the sources haven't changed.

I realize I've come up with a complicated solution. If you have a much simpler way to solve this problem, I'm open to suggestions--in that case, I'll edit the name of this question to be appropriate.

Comment: Your description of problem 2 is unclear. The receiver (launched by the `server` rule) directs the output to `product_name.pipe`, and the the `%.enums` rule renames that file to something else. What's the problem?

Comment: You could reduce all to a single target `%.enums` by using batch loops as you state in your question. Any reason not to do that ?

Comment: @Beta--I guess I you're right. product_name.pipe is just a temporary file. I'll edit my question to make it clear that it's a temporary file and remove item #1.

Comment: @perencia--Somehow, using a batch loop seemed dirty to me. However, I'm very Windows-specifc as is (i.e. `cmd /c start /B`). Care to add a version using a batch loop as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this old question while solving a similar problem. Just turn your "*dummy*" files into real (empty) ones to keep track of the last time you processed a source file. In the following I group them in a subdirectory (`dummies`) such that they do not interfere too much with the source tree:

```
D_DIR = dummies
D_FILES = $(patsubst %.c,$(D_DIR)/%.dummy,$(SRCS))   # All dummy files

$(D_DIR)/%.dummy : %.c
    [ -f server ] || { cmd /c start /B ExtractEnums.exe -server > temp.pipe && touch server; }
    cmd /c parser.exe $(DEFINES_AND_OPTS) -e $^ | cmd /c ExtractEnums.exe -client
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) # create dummy's directory if it does not exist
    touch $@           # create dummy

# Extract enums from all the preprocessed source:
%.enums : $(D_FILES)
    cmd /c echo ;;exit;; | cmd /c ExtractEnums.exe -client
    rm -f server
    cmd /c move temp.pipe $@
```

Note: I also use an empty dummy file (`server`) to mark the server as running and launch it only if needed in the dummy's recipe. This avoids having it as a prerequisite of each dummy and re-building a dummy if its corresponding source file did not change but the server is not running.